# Is it possible to setup VSCode to show closing tags (or brackets) on the same line as all normal code editors do?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am waiting for this feature for years and finally thinking to get back to WebStorm just because the Devs just ignoring this simple feature. All plugins I've tried that should fix that closing bracket bug (from user perspective this is deffinatly a bug) are too buggy at the moment. Maybe someone found good working plugin to fix this?

PS. Really? Looks like those devs are minusing my post )))

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get what I want using this VSCode plugin:
[Explicit Folding](https://github.com/zokugun/vscode-explicit-folding)

Just instaled plugin and added this to VSCode's settings.json:

```
"folding": {
 "*": [
  {
    "begin": "{{{",
    "end": "}}}"
  },
 ],
 "typescript": [
  {
    "begin": "[",
    "end": "]",
  },
  {
    "begin": "{",
    "end": "}",
  }
 ],
 "typescriptreact": [
  {
    "begin": "{/*",
    "end": "*/}"
  },
  {
    "begin": "[",
    "end": "]",
  },
  {
    "begin": "{",
    "end": "}"
  },
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of VS Code 1.39, you cannot change how folding works. This request feature is tracked by https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3352

Answer (score 1):

@Matt, I hope they finally will make it someday )

Btw, stop silently disliking this post, stand up and say loudly, where I am not right!

[image]

[image]

As I understood, they says "If you want it, than make it yourself".
Perfect approach )))